# Azure ad b2c account lockout

Tags: azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-graph-api

Is there a way to configure account lock-in Azure AD B2C?
As of my research, I was able to find out that azure locks the account after 10 unsuccessful login attempts and locks it for 60 seconds. But I want to configure the number of attempts to 5, the account to be locked forever and won't display a message to the user to call our customer care or follow certain steps to get the account unlocked. I want a graph API call to unlock the clocked account.

Any pointers in this regard will be helpful.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe you can configure this lockout information using either the Azure Portal or the Azure AD Graph API.

(I wish, in future, Azure AD B2C allows customization of [the smart lockout values that are supported by Azure AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-password-smart-lockout#manage-azure-ad-smart-lockout-values).)